# RegExp for Javascript which allows everything but " and %

Tags: javascript, regex

In regular expression:

`var r = new RegExp('^[^%"]*$');`

what does `^` and `$` signifies? Does it means start and end of string or something else.

Also what if I remove `^` and `$` something like:

```
var r = new RegExp('[^%"]*');
```

Is this a valid regular expression  ?

Comment: You don't really need to type `new RegExp`. `var r = /^[^%"]*$/;` is fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

> what does ^ and $ signifies ? Does it means start and end of string or
>   something else.

Outside of the `[]` character class, `^` matches the start of the line, and `$` matches the end of the line. Inside the `[]` character class, `^` (when used at the beginning of the class) indicates mathcing any characters *not inside* the character class.

> Also what if I remove ^ and $ something like: var r = new
>   RegExp('[^%"]*'); ? Is this a valid regular expression ?

Yes, this is valid, just that it won't accomplish much because there could be characters on either side of the negated match, and `*` matches 0 or more of the defined character class.

Use something like [regex101.com to test your expressions and play around](http://regex101.com/r/wQ5hH6).

Answer (score 0):

yes '^' and '$' both mean the end of the string, respectively. at least outside of a character class. in a character class ^ means not, so it will not match those negated charactes (% and single-quote in this case)
if you remove the `^` and `$` then the regex will probably pass even if the string has % or " in it, with other characters

Examples

```
"\"50\"%".match(/^[^"%]*$/); // equals null
"\"50\"%".match(/[^"%]*/); //equals [""]
"\"50\"%".match(/[^"%]*/g); //equals ["", "50", "", "", ""]
```

Also in JS it is best practices to create your regex using /some regex/gm instead of new Regex("Some regex")

Comment: Why is it best practice to use */some regex/gm* ?

Comment: I don't agree with the `gm` flags part. `g` is used only when you need to match all occurrences and `m` will treat line-break as a indicator of a new string.

Comment: it doesn't have to end in gm those are just flags to the regex engine (g means global, m means multiline, i means case-insensitive) I was just using them to show how to pass flags. When you create a regexp open with `new RegExp` you will have to worry about escaping. so if you are matching a regex that has " and ' in it, you'd have to escape one. That and using /regex/ looks better. there is probably more I am forgetting about it

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `^` and `$` can  be changed with the `m` flag value.

- If `m` flag is set, `^` and `$` will match respectively the beginning and the end of a **line**.
- If `m` flag is not set, `^` and `$` will match respectively the beginning and the end of **the entire string**.

Since an image is better than 1000 words, here are the regexes visually:

```
^[^%"]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
[^%"]*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]